# Create list with custom text jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create a list with customized text views, like the image bellow.

[image]

I tried to do that with a lazy column, but it does not work properly.
The problem is that row does not grow with the content created, I don't know how compose redraw that view behind de hood but it isn't working to me.

```
@Composable
fun NumberList(viewModel: HomeViewModel) {
    val gameList = viewModel.numberList //The list of numbers

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 24.dp),
        content = {
            item {
                gameList.forEach {
                    MegaCard(item = it)
                }
            }
        })
}

@Composable
fun MegaCard(item: String) {
    val itemList = item.split("-")
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 4.dp)
    ) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(3.dp)) {
            itemList.forEach { number ->
                GameCircle(number)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun GameCircle(number: String) {
    val megaColor = colorResource(id = R.color.mega_green)
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .drawBehind {
                drawCircle(
                    color = megaColor,
                    radius = this.size.maxDimension
                )
            },
        text = number,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
        color = Color.White,
        fontSize = 18.sp
    )
}
```

The final result is something like this bellow:
[image]

Comment: "The problem is that row does not grow with the content created" -- could you please explain in greater detail what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As more game numbers are added, I assume you want each row to grow vertically. If that's the case, the problem is that the total circle size exceeds the available space. You can use a FlowRow for this:

```
@Composable
fun MegaCard(item: String) {
   val itemList = item.split("-")
   Card(
       modifier = Modifier
         .fillMaxWidth()
         .wrapContentHeight()
         .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 4.dp)
   ) {
     FlowRow(modifier = Modifier.padding(3.dp)) {
         itemList.forEach { number ->
             GameCircle(number)
         }
     }
  }
}
```

You'll need to add the flow layout Gradle dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-flowlayout:0.25.1'
```

Also, unless you intend to treat them as one entity, I recommend not adding every row into a single item. The [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#multiple-elements-one-item) go into more detail on the pitfalls of doing so. Here's the final [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8puP.png) using FlowRow.

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you! It works like a charm. I never heard about FlowRow before.